# Dimming other cells in UICollectionView when a cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to build a `UICollectionView` for a messaging application, where each `UICollectionViewCell` in the `UICollectionView` corresponds to a message. I am using [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit), which extends `UICollectionView`, to handle the messages. When the user taps a message, I want to reveal information about the message (time sent, user reactions to the message, etc.).

GroupMe does this in a very elegant way by (1) expanding the message vertically to reveal information, and (2) *dimming the rest of the messages in the view and disabling user interaction for them*. Note that the highlighted `cell` is still interaction enabled.  See before/after images below.

[Before tapping message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScWhD.jpg)

[After tapping message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wxFH.jpg)

Here I am focused on achieving (2), i.e. when a message is tapped, I want to dim all other `cells` and disable user interaction for them. I also want to be able to animate this change so that it dims all the other `cells` over some short duration. When the user taps anywhere in the view, I'd like the highlighted `cell` to 'unhighlight', and user interaction to be re-enabled for all cells, and similarly animate the revert.

I'm a little stumped on how to achieve this behavior - any ideas on how to implement this in `Swift`? Any pointers that could get me started in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at `visibleCells` or `indexPathsForVisibleItems` and from there run a check on the indexPath and apply an alpha to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a UIView for each Cell’s subview, except for the one selected. This view could be animated by changing the alpha value with fading/appearing effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can `override` **`isSelected`** property in your custom `UICollectionViewCell` to handle the user interaction and `alpha` on `cell` selection, i.e.

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = self.isSelected
            self.alpha = self.isSelected ? 1.0 : 0.5
        }
    }
    
    //rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks straightforward. My question is does this get set for the other cells in the `UICollectionView` when one of them is selected? Or would I need to access those other cells separately somehow?